# Visualising multiple spherical particles translating and rotating in a box

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a simulation of particles that are translating and rotating inside a cubic box. I have a txt file of their positions. I need to import them to Blender and show their dynamics.

x_1 y_1 z_1 
x_2 y_2 z_2
.
x_N y_N z_N

and angular velocities (O - Omega)

Ox_1 Oy_1 Oz_1 
Ox_2 Oy_2 Oz_2 
.
Ox_N Oy_N Oz_N

from t_0 to t_m so I have 2m files in total.

Currently, I am using MATLAB to make a spherical mesh for each of the N spheres. I assign a orientation vector to them which rotates with Omega (this is equivalent to having an initial [theta, phi] for each sphere and updating them with Omega)

I have done this with a pair of spheres (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONPJZreQC8), but it does not look good with multiple spheres. I would like to use Blender to make the visuals more appealing. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have not used Blender before.

Comment: could you pls explain how it should look like or even better insert an image/sketch how it should look? The problem about "more appealing" is: we don't know what you mean with that and the opinion might differ from individuals what more appealing means/is.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, here is a sample movie made using MATLAB
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JY_P2UEA0FV7NOoRSUIP6dst-T0hsfXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so now your problem is just the texturing of the sphere? or did i misunderstand that?

Comment: Yes. 
I have txt files of the locations x,y,z. The spheres are of radius 1.  I have their angular velocities as well Omega_{x,y,z}. In Matlab I assign a orientation vector to each sphere at time t_0 and advance it. d(p)/dt = Omega x p. Then I generate multiple sphere that rotate and translate. 

I hope to do this in Blender but I have no prior experience with it. I realize I need to use Rigid body animation (not physics). Hence, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the text files I have are named as  

pos00xxx.txt 
ang00xxx.txt 

where x goes from 0 to 100 for example. Hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: uhm...now you confused me a bit more ;) In Blender you can use rigid bodies. But as long as you don't check the "animated" checkbox, Blender calculates all positions and rotations for you. You cannot change the positions and rotations by yourself (or your text file). If you check the "animated" checkbox, you can change positions and rotations (but honestly, then you don't need rigid bodies, because you are already animating your objects manually).

Comment: ok, proposal: can you pls provide us a small example of your txt file (maybe add is as text in the question or as download link from some cloud provider) and then we can try to help you a bit more concrete. Is animation nodes (a free add-on) as solution ok?

Comment: Okay sorry, I am probably wrong then.

I do not need Blender to do any physics. I will give it the location of my 'N' spheres for each time and the angular velocities (equivalently the orientation vector or spherical coordinate angles). Will it be able to make a movie like how I have made in MATLAB ? 

I can share the txt datafiles and my MATLAB script file if that will be helpful.

Comment: yes, this can be done pretty easily via animation nodes ;) (...BUT...only of course it is just easy, if you have coordinates and rotation angles). If you really have angular velocities, you would have to calculate the rotational angle per frame per object somehow in your code (which isn't trivial i assume). Because Blender can only "work" with positions and angles, not with velocities.

Comment: I assume these angles that Blender asks are alpha, beta and gamma in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations

So I assume it creates a rotation matrix in 3D and rotates the object. 

If this is true, then I can provide these angles quite easily by doing a Euler explicit time marching.

d(alpha)/dt = Omega_x, d(beta)/dt = Omega_y, d(gamma)/dt = Omega_z

Comment: ok, great, then i can show you how to make an animation from these data with animations nodes....i will write an answer, if animation-nodes is ok for you?

Comment: Thank you Chris. 

Here are the files. I generated the 3 angles for the 3 directions (as you can see in the script process.m) So the raw files needed for Blender should be pos00***.txt and ang00xxx.txt.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16M8tfbvCWspKMVOi50r1ciHNCd6YkpLm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is my "first shot":

It has following restrictions:

1. i animated just one object
2. the first 3 values are x,y,z and then follow the rotation values

i used this animation nodes setup:

[image]

The text block reader reads your data from text file (there is a text-editor in Blender, where you can copy & paste the data in).

This is my text file (which i used for my little test):

[image]

Afterwards i am just "parsing" the data by separating by lines, then by "," to separate the single values and combining them again to position and rotation vectors.

The object transform output node then uses this data to change the object itself.

result:

[image]

if this is, what you need and you are happy with this, i will update my answer so that it works for more than just one object

UPDATE:

So, here is a node tree, how you can read multiple files with AN:

[image]

afterwards you have to parse the data as i showed you in the first node tree.

of course you have to adapt the path that it fits to your directories.

Comment: This looks great. (I should have said earlier that I am doing molecular dynamics type simulations and have used VMD software before. But I was unable to show rotations with VMD.)

Is it possible to load multiple files into Blender automatically (like PARAVIEW. It recognises sequentially made *.vtk files)

Comment: Or I must use a script like BPY (https://pypi.org/project/bpy/)

Comment: no, you can do this with AN too...give me a bit time ;), but yes, would be possible with python too but more complicated...i think. But if you are a python expert, it might be easier for you ;)

Comment: i updated my answer so now you should be able to read multiple files.

Comment: Beautiful !! thank you very much. I will give it a try and update here (I will not be as fast as you I am sure)

Comment: you are welcome! I had fun figuring it out myself ;)